# Freezing burnt aubergine flesh

Tags: freezing, eggplant

When making dishes involving charred aubergines (e.g., Baba Ganoush), I often find myself producing more aubergine flesh than I need for a meal or two. I'm now wondering if the aubergine flesh would be amenable to freezing: going by [How can I tell if a vegetarian recipe is suitable for freezing?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16077/how-can-i-tell-if-a-vegetarian-recipe-is-suitable-for-freezing/16868#16868), since I *want* to dry out the flesh a bit anyway, it might work, but I'm not sure if it would destroy the texture. Has anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freezing always softens vegetables, including cooked ones. For baba ghanouj I don’t think it would matter since you’re mincing/pureeing it anyway. Dehydration isn’t a major concern as long as you tightly wrap it and protect it from temperature fluctuations.

Anecdotally, roasted eggplant definitely comes out quite soft in defrosted curry leftovers but it still holds together fine.

Comment: Agree and would recommend storing in freezer bags, where you can squeeze out as much air as possible, and lie flat (at least for initial freezing).  The flat, frozen product thaws much quicker than a block in a container.